# How to use javascript library? (Ember JS)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, twitter, web-applications, bower

Simple question here, but I can't seem to figure out how to use a dependency I've installed in my ember JS app.  I installed the [twitter fetcher](https://github.com/jasonmayes/Twitter-Post-Fetcher) library [via bower](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/addons-and-dependencies/managing-dependencies/#toc_bower).

[image]

I have a twitter-container component, and inside of my component.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
loadPlugin: function() {
    var config1 = {
      "id": 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      "domId": 'example1',
      "maxTweets": 1,
      "enableLinks": true
    };
    twitterFetcher.fetch(config1);
  }.on('init')
});
```

I get a 'twitterFetcher is not defined' error (obviously), but am not sure how to import it.  Should I include a line like this?

```
import twitterFetcher from 'bower_components/twitter-fetcher'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ember-cli-build.js, you need to include the below line to bundle it in ember app,

```
app.import('bower_components/twitter-fetcher/js/twitterFetcher_min.js')
```

you can refer it as `window.twitterFetcher`

Comment: then you can window.twitterFetcher direclty. it might work

Comment: window.twitterFetcher did it - knew it was something simple.  Thanks!